# save a mp3 genre in id3 tag version 1

Tags: c#, id3

I have a trouble with saving id3 genre in my wpf program.

I can save other factors such as Song title, Singer, Album, Year...
But, except Genre.

As you see my example code above, If I save Genre as int 10 or any number, the result gives 0, not 10 or any number. 
I don't know why.

Here is my code snipet.

```
    byte GetBytesInt32(int argument)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(argument);
        return byteArray[0];
    }
    private byte[] GetTagBytes
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] Buf = new byte[128];
            Array.Clear(Buf, 0, 128);
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes("TAG").CopyTo(Buf, 0);
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes(타이틀.Text).CopyTo(Buf, 3);
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes(가수명.Text).CopyTo(Buf, 33);
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes(앨범.Text).CopyTo(Buf, 63);
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes(년도.Text).CopyTo(Buf, 93);
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes("").CopyTo(Buf, 97);

            Buf[126] = GetBytesInt32(10); 
            Buf[127] = GetBytesInt32(10);//currentGenre;

            return Buf;
        }
    }

    private async void BT_infoUpdate_Click()
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
            fs.Write(GetTagBytes, 0, 128);
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (fs != null) fs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: WPF is a UI framework, and the tag does not seem relevant here.

Comment: sorry. I mean the tag is a  id3 tag, not wpf tag.

Comment: And I meant that the *question* should not be tagged `wpf`, since the is no wpf code here (since wpf code is a UI Framework, and there is no UI code, that tag is not appropriate).

Comment: oh. I finally understood it. So, I removed wpf tag. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean that Genre is 0? Where do you see this value?

Comment: As you see my example code above, If I save Genre as int 10 or any number, the result gives 0, not 10 or any number. I don't know why.